# How to use Textresource in GWT

Tags: gwt, clientbundle

I'm using GWT for a Webapplication. Now I tried to include a Textresource (HTML-File) like it's described here: http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideClientBundle.html#TextResource 
I got a errormessage like:

```
No source code is available for type my.package.resources.MyHTMLResource; did you forget to inherit a required module?
```

When I remove the MyHTMLResource.java and the resources from the package "my.package.resources" and putting them into the package "my.package.client" where the EntryPointClass is, everything works fine. But I'd like to seperate the resourcefiles from the other files.

So how can I move the resourcefiles and the MyHTMLResource.java File in an other package?
Do I have to change something in the .gwt.xml file?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I put my resources into a subpackage of the client package:

```
my.package.client.resources
```

You can also fix it by [adding a source entry to your gwt.xml](http://www.gwtapps.com/doc/html/com.google.gwt.doc.DeveloperGuide.Fundamentals.Modules.ModuleXml.html).